# Substituting with Bacon and Bacon Fat in a Recipe

Tags: substitutions, fat, bacon

I've been thinking about throwing cooked bacon into various recipes like candy and bread. Are there any general guidelines for adjusting the recipes for handling this addition? For example, should I lessen the amount of fat or salt to adjust for the same coming from the bacon?

On the same note, what fats can I substitute bacon fat for? I know it is a liquid when heated up but solid in the fridge. Does it work in place of butter, oil, etc?

Comment: I used bacon in cookies with great success. I started by putting the bacon in a roasting tray and covering with brown sugar. Throw it in the oven. Half way through, flip the bacon and add more brown sugar. Dice it small and then throw it in cookies with chocolate chips. Delicious.

Comment: +1 on the question for something I've never considered doing, +1 for yossarian because that sounds delicious and crazy at the same time. I hope I am adventurous enough to try this...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Bacon fat is a liquid and salty, adjust both in your recipes (unless you want moist or salty)
- Baking is pickier about fat ratios (so swap other fats out), and cooking is less picky (more fat is usually just tastier)
- Bacon fat does solidify at room temperature, but in small quantities can be used to replace any oil (I often use it to sweat onions)
- You can use the creamier texture of bacon fat in soups and sauces for a super mouth feel

Comment: For what it's worth, I save and add bacon fat to many dishes.  Soup (as mentioned), starting stocks, savoury pancakes, meat balls/hamburger patties/meatloaf, dips.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of chemistry, I don't think there is much special about bacon grease as opposed to any other animal-derived fat product (melted fatback, lard, whatever). It's purely about that salty smoky taste.

Not much that has that flavor except bacon, but the flavor itself isn't critical (though it is damn tasty). I'd just accent some other flavor in the dish, and add more salt than the recipe calls for. Won't be the same, but it shouldn't be too bad either.

Comment: I know this is over 3 years later, but since you're still around... I think you misread the question. He wants to *add* bacon, not remove it! :)